# NodeJS, Selenium webdriver, and jenkins pipeline error "Unable to obtain driver"

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

I have searched everywhere to find a solution for this and its been a week but cant find anything.
My current project uses javascript, nodejs, and selenium webdriver to do some automation testing on chrome. I have set up my pipeline script to in jenkins and it keeps failing at the last step when it tries to build the browser, what am i missing here? I'm using a windows machine and the jenkins agent is a linux agent, so i tried adjusting Path for the chrome binary.

I'm using a Docker image for nodejs(i've tried using the nodejs plugin with selenium image), and manually installing google chrome and driver to the linux agent.

Im new to all of this so please any guidance will be appreciated

JavaScript code:

```
    console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");const chrome = require('selenium-       webdriver/chrome');const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

```
describe('Automation test', async function () {let driver;
```

```
this.timeout(190000); // set a timeoutconsole.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");before(async function () {console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");const loggingPrefs = new Preferences();loggingPrefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);const options = new chrome.Options();options.setLoggingPrefs({ performance: 'ALL' });options.addArguments("--incognito");options.addArguments("--headless");options.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable');const caps = Capabilities.chrome();caps.setLoggingPrefs(loggingPrefs);console.log("AUTOMATION IS TRYING TO RUN!");const chromedriverPath = '/tmp/bin/chromedriver';process.env['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriverPath;
```

```
driver = new Builder().withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build();
```

Pipeline Script in jenkins:

ERROR:
Error: Unable to obtain browser driver.
For more information on how to install drivers see